# How to find chained data?

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a below table.

**chained_schedule**:

```
chained_id  parent_schedule_id  next_schedule_id
  1               71                    72
  2               72                    73   
  3               74                    75
```

When I give as input `parent_schedule_id=71`, output should find that particular record and the record identified by its `next_schedule_id`, which again can chain to another record,  ...etc.

So for the above data and query, the output should be like this:

```
chained_id  parent_schedule_id  next_schedule_id
  1               71                    72
  2               72                    73
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What????  Elaborate please what you're actually doing

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: if you give parent_schedule_id=71, only first row should be selected. Why row 2 having parent_schedule_id 72??

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support some form of recursive CTEs.  The ANSI syntax is:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select cs.*
      from chained_schedule cs
      where parent_schedule_id = 71
      union all
      select cs.*
      from chained_schedule cs join
           cte 
           on cte.next_schedule_id = cs.parent_schedule_id
    )
select *
from cte;
```

Comment: can we implement this CTEs using spring data jpa?

Comment: I don't use use spring data jpa.  You can implement this in any database that supports ANSI standard recursive CTEs (Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Teradata all come to mind).

Comment: I tried to run this query in oracle 11g , but i am getting error at line no. 1 (missing keyword)

Comment: @ShrutiHowal . . . Oracle started supporting recursive CTEs in version 12c.

Comment: Is any other way to get the solution of above question , that 11g can support?